# Why did my hollow-wall anchor slip through the drywall?

Tags: drywall

I drilled a 5/16 hole and placed anchor, then tried to drive the screw in. Everything went through the wall.

I have 5 holes in this wall. One went in easily after I managed to hit a stud. There is no stud on the right side to hang my closet shelf for my clothes. The previous shelf broke.

I need to get this finished so I can hang up my clothes

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. If you'll take the [tour], you'll note that this is a Question & Answer board, not a general discussion forum. As such, we like to see a clear, concise question asked in the "Ask your question" box. Please [edit] your question to help clarify. You drilled 5/16" holes before installing screws, then put in a drywall anchor and ended up pushing the whole thing through the drywall? In that case, it sounds like your pilot hole was too big for the anchor. If you'll include the brand/model of the anchors, someone may be able to tell you what size pilot hole to drill.

Comment: If stuff is heavy enough to break a shelf or pull a shelf from the wall, I would want to depend on screws in studs instead of anchors in drywall.

Comment: Please edit your question and show us a pic of the specific type of drywall anchor you're trying to use, and also a pic of the hole you drilled.

Answer (score 2):

> I drilled a 5/16 hole and placed anchor, then tried to drive the screw in.

Was the anchor hard to put into the hole? If not, you might have "slopped" the hole with your drill . In other words, the drill moved a lot when you were drilling, and the drill bit shaved a lot off the hole. It's an easy mistake to make, especially if you've not used a drill a lot.

> there is no stud on the right side to hang my closet shelf for my clothes. The previous shelf broke.

You **NEED** another stud somewhere. If you're hanging clothes off this, a drywall anchor won't cut it. Heck, I wouldn't even risk the super-duper pricey anchors for this job.

To put it another way, your clothes weigh a lot. Seriously, go pick up a small section of the clothes you want to hang on this and see how heavy that is. Drywall is not an acceptable medium to mount into.

You should have studs to mount to. Most homes space them 16" on center. If you're not sure if there's a stud there, take a 1/16" drill bit and find out. The holes are easy to patch and will likely be behind your shelf anyway. If the studs are not convenient, mount a 2x4 to your studs and then attach the shelf to that.

Comment: It really depends on the configuration of the shelf and its anchoring points. A shelf that spans between walls and is anchored at the front corners and the back doesn't need as heavy-duty an anchor as a shelf with only strut supports.

Answer (score 1):

Plug-type drywall anchors are fussy. You need to do several things just right for them to work.

1. Drill *clean* holes just the right size. Any tearing or blowout of the hole dramatically reduces grab. Use a sharp bit and be steady to prevent oversize due to drill wobble. Spin quickly and press lightly.
2. Press the anchor in firmly before inserting the screw. Give the anchor a chance to engage with the drywall and hold rotational position.
3. Use exactly the right size screw. Too small and the plastic will strip. Too large and the screw will grab too hard and spin the anchor.
4. Press lightly when driving the screw, and stop immediately if the anchor starts to spin. If that happens, you'll need a different type of anchor to reuse the same hole.
5. Don't overtighten. Use your drill's clutch to limit the force applied to the screw and anchor. Only snug enough to secure the hardware.

Plug anchors are included in hardware kits because they're inexpensive. The ones which are little more than plastic tubes should always be discarded. Good ones have taper and a flange on top.

Other types of anchors have more positive expansion and holding power. It may be well worth the small cost to upgrade for your project.

Comment: I'm gonna also recommend not using a drill or driver to install the anchor and screw (drilling the hole with a power tool is fine).  When using a power tool it's easy to overspin the anchor and/or screw, causing the anchor to get loose in the hole.  Install the anchor and screw by hand.

Comment: My arm aches just thinking about cranking half a dozen screws in by hand. Modern drills have very effective clutches for just this purpose.

Comment: A newbie (no stud finder) probably isn't gonna know how to properly use that.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different anchors designed to hold screws in drywall.

Some such as [these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01FCZ8I3I) don't require any holes to be predrilled and come in a variety of sizes to hold different weights.

There is also this type of anchors for very heavy loads:

[image]

Comment: Good information, but I'm not sure how this answers the question of why an anchor punched through the drywall.